# Can Services in GCP's Monitoring monitor endpoints?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-anthos, sre

I installed managed Anthos on a GKE cluster. Anthos Service Mesh is working and is displaying my API. Thanks to that Services that are in Monitoring automatically detect my API. This is great as it enables me to easily set SLOs and Error Budget for my API.

However I would like to be able to easily set SLOs for individual endpoints in my api. Services(in Monitoring) detect only my API and not the endpoints within my API(my API is one pod/container + sidecar). I tried to add endpoints to Services in Monitoring but it looks like it is only possible to add Kubernetes Objects there.

Is there a way to use Services in Monitoring with endpoints? Is the only way to do so to break endpoints to separate microservices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor your endpoints using **Cloud Endpoints with OpenAPI**, which allows you to monitor the health of APIs you own by using the logs and metrics Cloud Endpoints maintains for you automatically. When users make requests to your API, **Endpoints** logs information about the requests and responses and also tracks three of the four golden signals of monitoring: latency, traffic, and errors. These usage and performance metrics help you monitor your API.

The following URL [Configuring Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/configure-endpoints)  has the configuration process for **Cloud Endpoints**. Use this URL [Monitoring your API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/monitoring-your-api) as a reference on the monitoring process for your API, and this last URL for the [Cloud Endpoint’s overview](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints).

Comment: Thanks, do Cloud Endpoints also have such a great feature for creating SLOs and Error Budgets like Services in Monitoring and Service Mesh in Anthos?

Comment: Actually, you can use **GCP’s Service Monitoring** and its **SLOs** with **Cloud Endpoints**. Use the following URL as a reference [SLO Monitoring](https://medium.com/google-cloud/some-time-ago-i-looked-at-using-the-service-monitoring-api-to-create-basic-slos-against-out-of-b3555b08036f)